# Dynamic dictionary keys inside formatted string

Tags: python, string-formatting

Consider this simplified example of using a dictionary in string formatting:

```
template = 'My name is {name}, I am {ages[name]} years old and I am a {occupations[name]}.'

ages = {'name 1': 25, 'name 2:': 22}
occupations {'name 1': 'programmer', 'name 2': 'mechanic'}

for name in ages.keys():
    print(template.format(ages=ages, occupations=occupations, name=name))
```

which results in `KeyError: 'name'`

OK, fair enough, maybe I need

```
template = 'My name is {name}, I am {ages[{name}]} years old and I am a {occupations[{name}]}'
```

But no, `KeyError: '{name}'`

I know that in this instance I can do

```
template = 'My name is {name}, I am {age} years old and I am a {occupation}.'
(...)
print(template.format(age=ages[name], occupation=occupations[name], name=name))
```

Or you can zip the dicts and loop over both the keys and the items, but is there a way to do it more akin to my first example, i.e. supplying the complete dictionaries to `.format()` that works for any number of dicts?

In other words: Is there any way to use dynamic keys in a formatted string in Python?

Comment: `for name, age in ages.items():`? Or if you made it `[{"name": "name 1", "age": 25}, ...]` that would be easier to work with because you could just `**` unpack each dict.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's only possible if there's only a single dict. I'm looking for a solution for any number of dicts. Maybe I should have made my example slightly less simplified..., I'll edit the question

Comment: No, you need to write that loop yourself. You could obviously encapsulate it in a function if you wanted to reuse it, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the ages dict items and pass this to .format()

```py
template = 'My name is {name} and I am {age} years old.'

ages = {'name 1': 25, 'name 2': 22}

for name, age in ages.items():
    print(template.format(age=age, name=name))
```

Output:

```
My name is name 1 and I am 25 years old.
My name is name 2 and I am 22 years old.
```